# Normal GET request not working in Chrome (API)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, fetch

I noticed some strange behaviour from chrome on a simple GET request from a Public API. I tested the same code on Mozilla and I get no errors, but Chrome keeps throwing me errors about this. Can someone help me say why my GET call isn't working on chrome?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {getPokemon} from './services';
class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {


        name : "",

    }
}

  onClick(){ getPokemon().then((response) => { this.setState({ name: response.name })
       })
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={(e) => this.onClick(e)}> Click me</button>

          <h2> {this.state.name}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Fetch call:

```
export const getPokemon = () => {
    return fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/blastoise`).then((response) => {
        if(response.statusText === 'OK') {
            return response.json();
        }
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
    })
}
```

React & Console error:

[React Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O74p9.png)

Btw I already remove all my chrome files and reinstalled them.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

[Response.statusText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/statusText) is experimental and the `Response` in Chrome has `statusText` property as an empty string. A simple change would be to update your conditional statement to:

```
if(response.status === 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what it returns

```
{
 body: ReadableStream,
 bodyUsed: false,
 headers: {},
 ok: true,
 status: 200,
 statusText: "",
 type: "cors",
 url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/blastoise/"
}
```

So you are probably looking for either `ok` or `status`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using fetch method and you might be knowing that you cant check `response.status`  as fetch only fails when a network error is encountered or CORS is mis-configured on the server side kind of error. For redirection and all other errors it still comes as success

Please read it : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Right way of actual success checking for fetch method is below : Check for  `response.ok`

```
.then(function(response) {
   if(response.ok) {
      console.log("success");
   }
   throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
}
```